# No print messages inspite of instantiating a class - Python

Tags: python

I'm having 2 files namely misc.py which contains class declarations and misc_main.py which contains instantiation of the class.

`misc.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class dummy:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dummyPrint(self):
        print "Welcome to Python!"
```

`misc_main.py`:

```
from misc import dummy

dummyObj = dummy()
dummyObj.printDummy()
```

When compile it as below

```
$python misc.py misc_main.py
```

I do not see any print messages i.e., Welcome to Python

What am I doing wrong? Any better way of doing it?

Comment: Just use `python misc_main.py` Only execute the file in which your are creating an instance of class `dummy`

Answer (score 2):

You need to run *just* `misc_main.py`:

```
python misc_main.py
```

When you use run `misc.py misc_main.py` the second argument is only passed to `sys.argv[1]`, it does *not* tell Python to run both scripts.

Effectively, Python then just runs `misc.py`, which doesn't have any top-level statements that would print anything. Running `misc_main.py` *instead* on the other hand, will cause Python to find the `misc.py` file as a module when the `from misc import dummy` is run.

Python compiles Python files to bytecode transparently, as you run the files. For modules (such as `misc.py` here) a `.pyc` *bytecode cache file* is created, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not a "compile need" (actually, it is but Python does compiling transparently),it needs to be just **interpreted** so you should ;

```
python misc_main.py
```

Comment: Python does compile, but it does this transparently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, you are right, i just wanted to make it "simple"

Comment: @Kelly: you misspelled `dummy`; 3 mmms instead of two.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 

What does compiling transparently mean?

Comment: @Kelly: When you use the `python` command line, Python runs the requested script or module. If there is no byte-cache file for that script or module to load, Python compiles the file before running. The same applies to any module you import. This is not something you need to worry about.